# How do I display the label/value of buttons in PyGTK?

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm currently programming with Python GTK and I'm working on a Calculator. I created the Buttons and the Text Entry. Now I want to connect those two widgets. So if I click one Button the label gets displayed in the Text Entry. I would hope for an easy answer because I'm just getting started with the Program.

Comment: Have a look at the demo application which comes with pygtk. There are many simple examples which can teach you how to use the widgets. Also, show us what you tried...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already solved my problem.